# display error when two strings are similar using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two columns named as 'Supervisor` and 'Examiner'. 'Examiner' is listed using dropdown menu.

I would like to use javascript to validate the value selected from examiner drop down menu, IF the value is the same as 'Supervisor' value, the border of the dropdown menu turns to red and submit button ('Generate Schedule') of the form will disabled.

This is the codes I got but I didn't work out for me (with dummny data):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Test
</title>
    <style>
        .error {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        return checkLecturer();
    }

    function checkLecturer() {
        var e = document.getElementById("examinerID");
        var ex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisorID"].value;

        if (sv === ex) {

            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "error";
            alert("you can\'t select " + ex);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('examinerID').onchange = function () {
            checkLecturer();
        };
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>    
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="generateSchedule" class="sky-form">
        <table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Student name</th>
                <th>Project title</th>
                <th>Supervisor name</th>
                <th>Examiner </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>def</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="supervisor" type="hidden" name="supervisorID" value="Kent" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="ddldiv" style="width: 150px; height: 22px;">
                        <select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;">
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">Suzy</option>
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">Kent</option>
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">John</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, in the real codes, the value of 'Supervisor' and 'Examiner' is dynamically generated from DB.

This is how the form look like:

[image]

Update:

```
     <label class="select">
        <center>
        <%
          try{
               //connection
                String query="select s.studentID,s.studentName,s.projecttitle,s.lecturerID, l.lecturerID, l.lecturerFullname from student s JOIN lecturer l ON s.lecturerID = l.lecturerID where rownum <=5";
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
               int i=1;
         %>
        <table id="t01">
        <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Student name</th>
        <th>Project title</th>
        <th>Supervisor name</th>
        <th>Examiner </th>
        </tr>
        <% while(rs.next()){ %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= i++ %>.</td>
        <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="studentID" style="" value="<%=rs.getString("studentID") %>">
        <%=rs.getString("studentName") %></td>
         <td style="width:30%;"><%= rs.getString("projectTitle") %></td>
         <td>
        <input id="supervisor" type="hidden" name="supervisorID" style="" value="<%=rs.getString("lecturerID") %>">
        <%=rs.getString("lecturerFullname")%>
        </td> //FOCUS ON HERE

           <td>

        <select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" onchange="checkLecturer()">
        <option selected disabled>Examiners Name</option>
                                                                         <%
         try{
                                                                             //connection
              String query1="select lecturerID, lecturerFullname from lecturer ";
              Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection(url1,username1,password1);
              Statement stmt1=con1.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery(query1);
               while(rs1.next())
                                                                             {

                                                                         %>

    <option value="<%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %>"><%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %> - <%=rs1.getString("lecturerFullname") %></option> //FOCUS ON HERE

         <%
        //closing connection for rs1 and exception  %> 
                                    </select>

        </td>

       </tr>
<%
        //closing connection for rs and exception
%>
</table> 

<footer>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button"> Generate schedule</button><br><br>

 </footer></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add values to your options, and remove the ids, id should be unique and not on an option element

```
<option value="Suzy">Suzy</option>
<option value="Kent">Kent</option>
<option value="John">John</option>
```

remove the onkeyup event, since this is a select element, use the onchange event.

```
<select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" style="width: 150px; height:30px;" onchange="checkLecturer()">
```

now you can extract the value just by using

```
document.getElementById("lecturerFullname").value

function checkLecturer() {
        // btw this is the name of the drop down not the id
        // var e = document.getElementById("examinerID"); 
        var ex = document.getElementById("lecturerFullname").value;

        var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisorID"].value;

        if (sv === ex) {

            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "error";
            alert("you can\'t select " + ex);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and in the checkLecturer function add the error class like you did,

NOTE: if at all possible add jquery or angular, this will make life a lot simpler for you

Using jquery:

```
function checkLecturer() {
    var lecturerFullname = $('#lecturerFullname').val();
    var compVal = $('#supervisorID').val();

    if(compVal.localeCompare(lecturerFullname) === 0) {
         alert('same thing');
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // add the event listender
    $('#lecturerFullname').on('change', checkLecturer); 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It is working but when I used on my real codes. It didn't work. This is my option value `<option value="<%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %>"><%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %> - <%=rs1.getString("lecturerFullname") %></option>` I would add up some of my codes..

Comment: are there any errors bying output to the developer console?

Comment: Error returns: `Uncaught ReferenceError: checkLecturer is not defined` at this line : `<select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" onchange="checkLecturer()">`

Comment: then your function is not defined ... do you have access to jquery?

Comment: i see @silicakes has added a nice fiddle that works you should check it out :)

Comment: Same problem. Not working when I try on my codes.. What access btw?

Comment: i mean can you add jquery? XD

Comment: And I understand yours better hehe

Comment: Oh thank you! I have a question.. When I first tried your code it is working fine. But when I implement in my codes, It did not work out?

Comment: i dont get the question :S

Comment: what you can do to debug it is look at the markup that is displayed compare the differences, because if the html/js is the same then there shouldnt be any error, maybe the ids or something idk

Comment: I did not add JQuery yet. I tried again the javascript. I am getting this error : `generateSchedule.jsp:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`. At this line : `document.getElementById("lecturerFullname").value`

Comment: then it cant find the lecturerFullname are you sure that is the id of your element?

Comment: its the ID in `<select>` right? `<div id="ddldiv" style="width: 150px; height: 22px;">
                                                                 <select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" onchange="checkLecturer()">
                                                                 <option selected disabled>Examiners Name</option>`

Comment: yes............, maybe you are calling the function before the document is loaded

Comment: well now it shows nothing -,- but still didnt work out. I give up lol

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a small example that suggests a way of tackling the issue:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/csapyn8q/2/

### HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Supervisor</th>
      <th>Examiner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>
        <select class="dropdown">
          <option>George Smith</option>
          <option>John Doe</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jim Hawkins</td>
      <td>
        <select class="dropdown">
          <option>Leslie Bell</option>
          <option>Jim Hawkins</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### JS

```
function validate(e) {
  var select = e.target;
  var index = select.selectedIndex;
  var examiner = select.children[index].textContent;
  var supervisor = select.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].textContent;

  if (examiner === supervisor) {
    select.className = select.className + " error";
  } else {
    select.className = select.className.replace(" error", "");
  }
}
var dropdowns = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown"));
dropdowns.forEach(function(dd) {
  dd.addEventListener("change", validate);
});
```

### CSS

```
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What we are essentially doing is binding our dropdowns to call the `validate()` function on every change and add a red border in case both examiner and supervisor are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
function validateForm() {
    return checkLecturer();
}  

function checkLecturer(arg) {
    var examinerValue = arg.value;
            console.log(examinerValue);
    var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisorID"].value;

    if (sv === examinerValue) {

        document.getElementById('lecturerFullname').className = "error";
        alert("you can\'t select " + ex);
        document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        return false;
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementById('lecturerFullname').className = "";
        return true;
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('examinerID').onchange = function () {
        checkLecturer();
    };
};
```

there should not be multiple id in html. This is wrong practices.